# LENGTH vs COUNT

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I know this is perhaps a very basic difference/question, but is there a general distinction between grabbing the `LENGTH` of something vs grabbing the `COUNT` when the data is not single-valued (i.e., it's an iterable, array, aggregation, etc.)

A few examples:

```
>>> len([1,2,3,4,5])
5

select count(*) from (
  select "1" union select "2" union select "3" union select "4" union select "5"
) x

count(*)
5
```

What is the difference between the two, or are they used interchangeably in certain cases (if so, when?)?

Comment: It's basically the difference of the dispatcher radioing a bus driver asking how many people are onboard and sending all the people to the dispatcher to get counted.

Answer (score 0):

The `COUNT` SQL function is performed by the database on the server side, so on the client side the Python script receives just an integer from the server, making it much more efficient than retrieving the full list of rows from the server only to count them on the client side with the `len` function in Python. On the other hand, if you actually need the data rather than just counting them, you should retrieve the rows and then use the `len` function to count them instead of using two SQL statements, one to query the data and the other to count them.